# How to list all the tasks in a console app?

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I need it for debugging, through the code and not through some UI tools.

The class `TaskScheduler` has the property `Current` which returns `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, but it is internal, apparently in taskschd.dll.

Also `GetScheduledTasks()` of `TaskScheduler` is protected
In other words, you cannot use it to list the tasks. I need to list all the tasks including those created indirectly inside the base NET code on behalf of my console app

Comment: Have you tried using reflection to access the internals? I'm not advicing this for production, just saying.

Comment: TaskScheduler has two internal methods that are used by the debugger, that's how it implements the Debug > Windows > Tasks tool window in VS.   The static TaskScheduler[] GetTaskSchedulersForDebugger() lets you iterate all schedulers, Task[] GetScheduledTasksForDebugger lets you iterate all the tasks for each scheduler.  Use reflection to call them.  Do beware that calling them while the program is running and actively creating/executing tasks is not particularly safe, not an issue with the debugger since it freezes the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [System.Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) api. You can query for non-public members by giving proper BindingFlags to reflection methods:

```
var type = typeof(TaskScheduler);
var fieldinfo = type.GetProperty("Current", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("GetScheduledTasks", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
```

..and after getting metadata for property and method, you can call [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx) or [MethodInfo.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx).